# reading a set of points from file and making a .OFF file

Tags: python, shell

I am having problem with adding a character at the start and the end of each line in a file and add ',' in between.

The file contains set of points:

```
657648.688 4772318.920 133.542
657650.269 4772318.841 133.578
```

So after editing the file contents should look like this:

```
[657648.688, 4772318.920, 133.542]
[657650.269, 4772318.841, 133.578]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So what have you done so far?can we have courtesy of your code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("input.txt") as infile, open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write("[" + ", ".join(line.strip().split()) + "]\n")
```

Comment: and also continuing with the same problem... how to read the above set of points from file into a list?
Thanks.

Comment: @saxenarajat99: `line.strip().split()` already gave you a list, why not use that?